# My universal image loader cannot load images

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

My images cannot load but my app is not crashing which is a good thing but it could be nice if the images can open
in the log cat, it says,  E/ImageLoader: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9e53e68]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
below is my code
here is my log cat

```
    E/ImageLoader: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9e53e68]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9e53e68]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is the BaseImageDownloader.java

```
/**
 * Retrieves {@link InputStream} of image by URI from other source with unsupported scheme. Should be overriden by
 * successors to implement image downloading from special sources.<br />
 * This method is called only if image URI has unsupported scheme. Throws {@link UnsupportedOperationException} by
 * default.
 *
 * @param imageUri Image URI
 * @param extra    Auxiliary object which was passed to {@link DisplayImageOptions.Builder#extraForDownloader(Object)
 *                 DisplayImageOptions.extraForDownloader(Object)}; can be null
 * @return {@link InputStream} of image
 * @throws IOException                   if some I/O error occurs
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if image URI has unsupported scheme(protocol)
 */
protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format(ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME, imageUri));
}
```

This is the load and display image task

```
   private Bitmap tryLoadBitmap() throws TaskCancelledException {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        File imageFile = configuration.diskCache.get(uri);
        if (imageFile != null && imageFile.exists() && imageFile.length() > 0) {
            L.d(LOG_LOAD_IMAGE_FROM_DISK_CACHE, memoryCacheKey);
            loadedFrom = LoadedFrom.DISC_CACHE;

            checkTaskNotActual();
            bitmap = decodeImage(Scheme.FILE.wrap(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        if (bitmap == null || bitmap.getWidth() <= 0 || bitmap.getHeight() <= 0) {
            L.d(LOG_LOAD_IMAGE_FROM_NETWORK, memoryCacheKey);
            loadedFrom = LoadedFrom.NETWORK;

            String imageUriForDecoding = uri;
            if (options.isCacheOnDisk() && tryCacheImageOnDisk()) {
                imageFile = configuration.diskCache.get(uri);
                if (imageFile != null) {
                    imageUriForDecoding = Scheme.FILE.wrap(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }

            checkTaskNotActual();
            bitmap = decodeImage(imageUriForDecoding);

            if (bitmap == null || bitmap.getWidth() <= 0 || bitmap.getHeight() <= 0) {
                fireFailEvent(FailType.DECODING_ERROR, null);
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        fireFailEvent(FailType.NETWORK_DENIED, null);
    } catch (TaskCancelledException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.e(e);
        fireFailEvent(FailType.IO_ERROR, e);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        L.e(e);
        fireFailEvent(FailType.OUT_OF_MEMORY, e);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        L.e(e);
        fireFailEvent(FailType.UNKNOWN, e);
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap decodeImage(String imageUri) throws IOException {
    ViewScaleType viewScaleType = imageAware.getScaleType();
    ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo = new ImageDecodingInfo(memoryCacheKey, imageUri, uri, targetSize, viewScaleType,
            getDownloader(), options);
    return decoder.decode(decodingInfo);
}

/** @return <b>true</b> - if image was downloaded successfully; <b>false</b> - otherwise */
private boolean tryCacheImageOnDisk() throws TaskCancelledException {
    L.d(LOG_CACHE_IMAGE_ON_DISK, memoryCacheKey);

    boolean loaded;
    try {
        loaded = downloadImage();
        if (loaded) {
            int width = configuration.maxImageWidthForDiskCache;
            int height = configuration.maxImageHeightForDiskCache;
            if (width > 0 || height > 0) {
                L.d(LOG_RESIZE_CACHED_IMAGE_FILE, memoryCacheKey);
                resizeAndSaveImage(width, height); // TODO : process boolean result
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.e(e);
        loaded = false;
    }
    return loaded;
}

private boolean downloadImage() throws IOException {
    InputStream is = getDownloader().getStream(uri, options.getExtraForDownloader());
    if (is == null) {
        L.e(ERROR_NO_IMAGE_STREAM, memoryCacheKey);
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            return configuration.diskCache.save(uri, is, this);
        } finally {
            IoUtils.closeSilently(is);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public InputStream getStream(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    switch (Scheme.ofUri(imageUri)) {
        case HTTP:
        case HTTPS:
            return getStreamFromNetwork(imageUri, extra);
        case FILE:
            return getStreamFromFile(imageUri, extra);
        case CONTENT:
            return getStreamFromContent(imageUri, extra);
        case ASSETS:
            return getStreamFromAssets(imageUri, extra);
        case DRAWABLE:
            return getStreamFromDrawable(imageUri, extra);
        case UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);`

Comment: `protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format(ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME, imageUri));
}`

Comment: Please tell the value of `imageUri`.

Comment: that file is a read only file

Comment: ???? Please tell the value of imageUri.

Comment: how do you do that

Comment: please help me out

Comment: `Log.d("value of imageUri: ", imageUri);` Then go to the Logcat, look and tell us. You could also use a Toast to toast its value.

Comment: Thank you sir I am new at this coding where should I insert the log.d in my grid adapter or the activity which the image can't be load or the universal image loader class

Comment: Where ever it is used. For instance in `getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri,...` or just before you call that function.